# SQL Server Cast varchar column value '1218300.00' as int

Tags: sql-server, casting, varchar

A large value in a column has caused my SQL to throw error msg: 
**Error converting data type varchar to numeric**

I have isolated this to a particular row. Here is a simplified script that "works":

```
SELECT 
  MtgeLoanAmount
  , CAST(convert(numeric(15,2),'1218300.00') as int) as TrialValue
FROM dbo.Processed_VA_From_Excel
  where FipsStateCode='06'
  and FipsCountyCode='013' 
  and GuarantyAmount = '304575'
```

which returns results as pasted here:
[image]

So when I try to "generalize" my test by adding a 3rd column as follows it fails to convert:

```
SELECT
MtgeLoanAmount
, CAST(convert(numeric(15,2),'1218300.00') as int)  as TrialValue 
, CAST(convert(numeric(15,2),MtgeLoanAmount) as int)
FROM dbo.Processed_VA_From_Excel
where 
    FipsStateCode='06'
and FipsCountyCode='013' 
and GuarantyAmount = '304575'
```

returns this:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

Comment: What is `MtgeLoanAmount` declared as?

Comment: Thanks, DeanOC. MtgeLoanAmount is declared as varchar(255) and most values are not as large as 1218300.00 (most all are less than 1 million)

Comment: 15,2 means total 15 out of which 2 are decimal points so there is larger value, get max and check and also you might need bigint to hold it instead of int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
SELECT
  MtgeLoanAmount,
  CONVERT(INT, ROUND(MtgeLoanAmount, 0)) AS MtgeLoanAmountNoCents
FROM
  dbo.Processed_VA_From_Excel
WHERE
  FipsStateCode = '06' AND
  FipsCountyCode = '013' AND
  GuarantyAmount = '304575'
```

Comment: Thank you, JohnS. I guess it was the magnitude of the number somehow. Your code suggestion above worked well.

Comment: Not the magnitude, the ROUND() function makes it work!